# how to create opacity for an image

Tags: html, css

I want to add an opacity background, with a visible text in front of an image.
In my case I used flex to display the div elements, and I tried to create a background with opacity and also with text for each div.
I know that I should use z-index to create background opacity layer, but in my case I don't know why it doesn't work.

```css
main{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.projects-wrapper{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
}
.projects-wrapper div{
    border: 2px solid green;
    flex-grow: 1;   
}
/* .projects-wrapper div.text-description{
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.projects-wrapper div.text-description span{
    display: block;
} */
.first-row div:first-child{
    background-image: url(../assets/concert-hall.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.first-row div:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url(../assets/bedroom-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.first-row div:last-child{
    background-image: url(../assets/hotel.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
 <main>
                    <div class="projects-wrapper first-row">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <!-- <div class="text-description">
                                Concert hall <span>in New York</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-category">
                                Architecture
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-wpapper">
                            <!-- <div class="text-description">
                                Modern bedroom <span>in Gorizia</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-category">
                                Interior
                            </div> -->               
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-wpapper">
                            <!-- <div class="text-description">
                                Modern hotel <span>in London</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-category">
                                Architecture
                            </div> -->                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
         <main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have given overlay background in class `image-wrapper` using ::after (pseudo-element). We have also wrapped **text-description** and **text-category** into div `description` and gave it position relative, z-index, and color. we have modified your style by assigning background image to direct child div. for example

```
.first-row div:first-child {
  background-image: url();
}
```

to

```
.first-row > div:first-child {
  background-image: url();
}
```

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/mt4zpa8q/

```css
main {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.projects-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
}

.projects-wrapper div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.first-row>div:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bedroom-ideas-rds-work-queens-road-08-1593114639.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.first-row>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bedroom-ideas-rds-work-queens-road-08-1593114639.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.first-row>div:last-child {
  background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bedroom-ideas-rds-work-queens-road-08-1593114639.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.description {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.text-description {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="projects-wrapper first-row">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="description">
        <div class="text-description">
          Concert hall <span>in New York</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-category">
          Architecture
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="description">
        <div class="text-description">
          Modern bedroom <span>in Gorizia</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-category">
          Interior
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="description">
        <div class="text-description">
          Modern hotel <span>in London</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-category">
          Architecture
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you need to use `z-index` to force the text to display on top of the background. I don't see you using it in your code, but if you're having trouble remember that the elements you're trying to overlay with `z-index` must be adjacent inside the same parent element, and both elements must be positioned, otherwise it just won't work.

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.container__background{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/720/1*LjR0UrFB2a__5h1DWqzstA.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .5;
}
.container__text{
  height: 100%:
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__background"></div>
  <div class="container__text">Put your text in here!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after`, `:before` CSS selectors. Also notice that in your HTML code you  have misspell "image-wrapper" to "image-wpapper". Here is your probable solution.

https://codepen.io/Umesh8965/pen/xxRErxV

Hope this will your expectation.